# I am completely confused as to this answer to a question on how to make a guessing game where you guess a number between 1 and 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

The code for [a guessing challenge](http://www.practicepython.org/solution/2014/04/10/09-guessing-game-one-solutions.html) is

```
import random

number = random.randint(1,9)
guess = 0
count = 0


while guess != number and guess != "exit":
    guess = input("What's your guess?")

    if guess == "exit":
        break

    guess = int(guess)
    count += 1

    if guess < number:
        print("Too low!")
    elif guess > number:
        print("Too high!")
    else:
        print("You got it!")
        print("And it only took you",count,"tries!")
```

Everything works in here fine, its not a coding issue...

My question is, why is the first guess variable 0? Then in the while loop ANOTHER guess variable is changed to input then changed to ANOTHER guess variable of integer...

Why can you change a variable 3 times? Is there a benifit to using guess 3 times as opposed to just coming up with a different variable name?

Comment: What would you initialize `guess` to instead, and why?

Answer (score 1):

> why is the first guess variable 0

Because a value for `guess` is needed in the comparison at `while`.

> Then in the while loop ANOTHER guess variable is changed to input

That's possible because Python is dynamically typed (aka. duck typing). You can assign a string here. Although I don't consider that a good programming style.

> then changed to ANOTHER guess variable of integer

Again, that's possible due to dynamic typing, not good coding style.

> Is there a benifit to using guess 3 times as opposed to just coming up with a different variable name?

No. Definitely not.

If you start using type hints in Python (like `# type: int`), the IDE will warn you when assigning strings to an integer variable. Here's a screen shot of PyCharm:

[image: Screenshot of a type hint warning in PyCharm]